# Inject JavaScript into UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, uiwebview, swift3

I am trying to inject a local JS file into a `UIWebView`. I have it set up to load the desktop version of the site but it does not appear to be working. I couldn't find anything in `Swift 3` to do this and tried to piece it together, but it seems I've hit a brick wall.

Here is what I have got so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": "custom value"])

    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/login")!))

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

        let jsPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mfpketo.user", ofType: "js")

        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: jsPath!)

        print("test")
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are almost close. You skipped important one line to load `JS` from `jspath` in

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: jsPath!)
```

Where you are mistakenly injecting js path instead of js itself. So, to load the content of the js file :

```
var js = try? String(contentsOfFile: jsPath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Then, handover the `js` to webview as usual.

```
 webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: js!)
```